# How to change AX2012 Excel export language - CTRL+T?

Tags: excel, axapta, dynamics-ax-2012, citrix

I'm using Dynamics AX 20102 by Citrix session.
In case I try to export by CTRL + T record,

I would like to change the *Excel language*.

Is it possible to make a setup or configuration in order to change the excel language?
For example, if I have my *AX user language* in English, I need to have the exported Excel page in Latin(just example...)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

`Ctrl+t` is handled by the kernel method [`\System Documentation\Classes\FormRun\task`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dynamics/ax-2012/system-classes/gg920296(v=ax.60)?redirectedfrom=MSDN), but you can intercept it in `\Classes\SysSetupFormRun\task`.

Specifically, you would look for `_p1 == #taskExportExcel` with the `#task` macro.

That is where you would put whatever code modification you'd do. For the language switching, I'm not clear whether you mean character encoding or the actual AX user language configuration that controls the labels and things. If it's the labels and things, you could just intercept `Ctrl+t` as I describe above and then before the `super()`, switch the user language, then after the `super()` switch it back.

If you're talking about character encoding, you would have to figure something else out depending on your needs.